# Outputting continuous data with Serial Communication

Tags: java, android, serial-port, android-sensors

I'm trying to send continuous sensor data from my smartphone to an Arduino through Serial Communication. I'm using the UsbSerial library (https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial/) for Serial Communication. I tried sending the data with a button press and it works perfectly, but now I'm trying to make the data send continuously. Whenever I try to run the code, however, the app keeps crashing. Do I have to put in a delay on start or how can I solve this?

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
int sensorType = event.sensor.getType();
switch (sensorType) {
case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
   final float accelX = event.values[0];

   String ax = "<"+ accelX +">";
   serialPort.write(ax.getBytes());
   break;
case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
   float magX = event.values[0];
   break;
}
```

This is the logcat screenshot as I try to upload it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzq4Q.png)

Comment: Can you share with us the logcat at the point of the crash? It provides details that will help infer possible causes.

Comment: It's not crashing in the Android Studio it only crashes when I try to load the app onto the smartphone. So no logcat when it crashes. It just says "{App Name} has stopped" and it shows the option "Open app again". If I click that option it crashes again and says "{App Name} keeps stopping" and then "Open app again" and "Close app".

Comment: There will be a logcat regardless of whether the app is running on an emulator or on a physical device. It is possible to view the logcat over adb, including using Android Studio.

Comment: Posted the logcat... it seems to get mad that I'm trying to enter an empty array?

Comment: It appears that `serialPort` is null; you'll need to review the code responsible for constructing a SerialPort and making sure that it actually gets called at the right time and runs properly. Perhaps there is a race condition where sensor readings are coming in before it's properly constructed, or that code might just not be getting called due to some other oversight.